# How to bundle a jar with Apple's new Java 6 for Mavericks, et al?

Tags: java, osx-mavericks, java-6, app-bundle

Java on Mac OS X has been an enormous headache.

Apple first made it clear they were turning Java releases over to Oracle, who provided only Java 7 and the [AppBundler](https://java.net/downloads/appbundler/appbundler.html) Ant task to package jars (and natives).

Oh, and Apple began insisting that App Store submissions use the AppBundler feature that copies the entire JRE - over 60mb. Yikes! So nothing to do but grind teeth and join the bloatware bandwagon...

Magically there is now a JRE 6 for Mavericks (published October 2013, but we weren't paying attention because Apple said their Java support was over). The packaging tool for JRE 6 is the old [JarBundler](http://informagen.com/JarBundler/) Ant Task, which does not support copying the JRE into the bundle.

**So here is the question: How to meet the new App Store standard of packaging the JRE with the app when the JRE 6-compatible bundling tool won't do it?**

NB: JarBundler uses an *Apple* binary `JavaApplicationStub` to invoke the JVM.  Having the stub look for the JVM inside the app bundle may be impossible? I cannot find any documentation on this.

FWIW, I need JRE 6 not just for the smaller footprint (about half the size), but also because JOGL (OpenGL Java binding) works great under 6 and is unusable under 7. Oracle diddled with the Swing innards in ways the JOGL guys (who are great by the way) haven't yet (after over a year) fully worked out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that only JRE 7 can be bundled on the app store. You might check the https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/java-dev archives, there should be plenty on this subject there.